# Number of price movements

Tags: pine-script

Is there a way in Pine Script, in Tradinview, to get the number of times price has moved during an interval period?
I'd like historical data too so just running a script that increments a variable every time the price changes is not ideal ...

As an example, I'd like to be able to say "the price has changed 120 times in the last 3 minutes".

Comment: Spend a big bag of money on the highest subscription tier with TV and check seconds data. Not the best solution, but the resolution is nice.

Comment: @karatedog, this would not give historical data, right?

Comment: It would give you historical data, just only for a very short period, like 1 or 2 days (for the 1 second data).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that on the historical bars as tick data is not available. For real time bars, you could use a `varip` counter and basically just do `cnt := cnt + 1` as the script will be executed with each new price movement.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of ... thanks!

Comment: If the script is executing on each price movement on the realtime candle, and he needs to count each price movement, why use `varip`?

Comment: @karatedog Because with `var` the intrabar executions won't persist. With `varip` he will have the intrabar history too. You can easily see this with `plotchar()` or something. Just create a `var` and a `varip` counters and increment them without any condition. See the output.

Comment: @vitruvius Yeah, I just realized that without `varip` the variable will be reset on each price movement. Even though I work with this, it still bites me in the back... :D Thanks.